# What has changed in the last 9 years to make 2.5" USB HDDs so much lighter?

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive

9-10 years ago, I bought a series of 2.5" USB HDDs from various brands. Recently, one of them died, after just 9 years of operating like half a day every six months at the most (more like every 8 months). I was hoping to *never* have to replace any of them.

Anyway, the new one (Seagate, 2 TB, bought today) is much lighter and feels much more "fragile" than the heavier ones I have from 9-10 years ago.

But it's still mechanical. Not an SSD. Those simply cost too much money for me to use for backups.

What has changed in the last few years which enable them to make the 2.5" external USB HDDs feel almost like the thin "cards" that SSDs are? And is this new one as "reliable" as the one it replaces? Or more reliable?

Comment: I have found consumer hard drives to be less reliable than good SSDs. I no longer use hard drives. Backups is one area where I had numerous failures.

Answer (score 1):

Data density increased, the height fell from 9,5 mm to 7 mm.

Unfortunately I can't tell if there were 9,5 mm drives with more than one platter inside.
Generally higher data density comes with more risk.

Reliability might sometimes be a firmware issue as some harddrive came with an aggressive head parking strategy in an effort to save energy thereby overstressing the mechanical parts.